# Is "released for a limited time" correct?

Tags: word-choice

> A special edition of the widely popular video game will be **released** for a limited time.

Does *released* work in that sentence?

Comment: A “release” is a single event. Once *released*, the game is “available” for a limited time.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is saying, in the future, the video game will be released for a period of time - after that period of time, the video game will no longer be available to buy.

So yes, it works.

Comment: See StephenS's comment above. "Release" normally refers to the date it is put on sale.